# Unknown device listed in iphone health app Data access and Devices

Tags: iphone, health.app, hacking

I have recently been concerned about activity on my Iphone 5e due to missing info and other concerning changes that I do not remember enacting, nor do I have reason to (accident is unlikely)

-Potentially sourced from an accidental malware download, Significant other installing spywars, or unknown action from another party

-Today, after prolonged investigation of device and logs, found multiple devices listed under Health app "data access and devices"

-My device is correctly designated "Aiphone", the second device is listed as "Adam's Iphone"

-I believed health app to be set to off, as well as most every other app, service, and icloud.  I turned off most everything in order to eliminate as many possibilities as I could

-I began to look deeper into the Health app settings after coming across the following IOS logs

````
 Jan 12 14:04:18 Adams-iPhone dasd(DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon)[126] <Notice>: NO LONGER RUNNING com.apple.healthd.periodic-data-collection:A10413 ...Tasks running in group [com.apple.dasd.default] are 0!
 Jan 12 14:04:18 Adams-iPhone UserEventAgent(com.apple.cts)[24] <Notice>: Rescheduling XPC Activity: com.apple.healthd.periodic-data-collection
 Jan 12 14:04:18 Adams-iPhone UserEventAgent(DuetActivityScheduler)[24] <Notice>: SUBMITTING: <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:18 Adams-iPhone UserEventAgent(DuetActivityScheduler)[24] <Notice>: Establish daemon connection; interrupted: 0
 Jan 12 14:04:18 Adams-iPhone dasd(DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon)[126] <Notice>: Submitted Activity: com.apple.healthd.periodic-data-collection:37B361 at priority 5 with interval 3600 <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:18 Adams-iPhone dasd(DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon)[126] <Notice>: Activity <private>: Optimal Score 0.7531 at <private> (Valid Until: <private>)
 Jan 12 14:04:18 Adams-iPhone contextstored(KnowledgeMonitor)[52] <Notice>: Idle Sleep Preventers Count: 1
 Jan 12 14:04:18 Adams-iPhone dasd(DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon)[126] <Notice>: Updating timeline: <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:18 Adams-iPhone dasd(DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon)[126] <Notice>: Current Probabilities: <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:18 Adams-iPhone dasd(DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon)[126] <Notice>: Next Probabilities: <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:18 Adams-iPhone dasd(DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon)[126] <Notice>: Updating Kill Count: <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:18 Adams-iPhone dasd(DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon)[126] <Notice>: Updating scores to <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone duetexpertd(AppPredictionInternal)[1368] <Notice>: Writing Action Predictions display cache
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: Calculating actions and expirers at Sun Jan 12 14:04:19 2020, blacklist = <private>, path = <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone kernel(corecapture)[0] <Notice>: 496855.437876 wlan0.A[37494] updateLQM@3336:No per core RSSI to report
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone pasted[206] <Notice>: BundleID com.apple.duetexpertd from team (null) (pid 1368) is requesting pasteboard com.apple.UIKit.pboard.general
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone pasted[206] <Notice>: Requesting local only pasteboard for com.apple.duetexpertd
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone runningboardd(RunningBoard)[26] <Notice>: [daemon<com.apple.pasteboard.pasted>:206] handle lookup could not find a matching process
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone pasted(AssertionServices)[206] <Notice>: BKSApplicationStateMonitor updated with invalid process
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone pasted[206] <Notice>: Client will receive device-locked general pasteboard.
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone pasted[206] <Notice>: ...requesting pasteboard com.apple.UIKit.pboard.general completed. Error: (null)
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone passd(PassKitCore)[123] <Notice>: Begin delaying exit: GetPasses (2)
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone passd(PassKitCore)[123] <Notice>: End delaying exit: GetPasses (1)
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone pasted[206] <Notice>: BundleID com.apple.duetexpertd from team (null) (pid 1368) is requesting pasteboard com.apple.UIKit.pboard.general
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone pasted[206] <Notice>: Requesting local only pasteboard for com.apple.duetexpertd
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone runningboardd(RunningBoard)[26] <Notice>: [daemon<com.apple.pasteboard.pasted>:206] handle lookup could not find a matching process
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone pasted(AssertionServices)[206] <Notice>: BKSApplicationStateMonitor updated with invalid process
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone pasted[206] <Notice>: Client will receive device-locked general pasteboard.
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone pasted[206] <Notice>: ...requesting pasteboard com.apple.UIKit.pboard.general completed. Error: (null)
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone duetexpertd(CallHistory)[1368] <Notice>: Setting limiting call kinds: <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone duetexpertd(CallHistory)[1368] <Notice>: Setting limiting call kinds: <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone duetexpertd(CallHistory)[1368] <Notice>: ==> <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone duetexpertd(CallHistory)[1368] <Notice>: Fetching from DB and updating cache. And coalescing: Yes, With callType limit: kCallTypeAll
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone duetexpertd(CallHistory)[1368] <Notice>: No calls to coalesce
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone duetexpertd(CallHistory)[1368] <Notice>: <== <private> returns 0 calls
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone duetexpertd(CallHistory)[1368] <Notice>: CHManager is getting destroyed...
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone passd(PassKitCore)[123] <Notice>: Begin delaying exit: GetPasses (2)
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone passd(PassKitCore)[123] <Notice>: End delaying exit: GetPasses (1)
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: <private> (JS): <private>
 Jan 12 14:04:19 Adams-iPhone HeuristicInterpreter[1369] <Notice>: Newly created actions and expirers: 16```

Should I be concerned?
````